# How do I format a DVD-RW?

Tags: dvd, restricted-formats

I have a dvd-RW-   /  Ubuntu (nautilus and KB3) recognise this DVD as DVD with restricted overwrite.  So i cannot reuse that DVD.  I had to pass in Windows - make him completely empty there, and return in Ubuntu.  Then everything work normal. (recognise the DVD as sequential).  Is there a explanation and a better solution?

Neither KB3 neither the terminal command: BD/DVD±RW/-RAM format utility by , version 7.1. :-( mounted media doesn't appear to be DVD±RW, DVD-RAM or Blu-ray. *** In this case the DVD was make "empty" with KB3. When I redo the same in Windows, it will work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of different options. I think the easiest is:

```
dvd+rw-format -force=full /dev/sr0
```

I also think that is the one most commonly already installed on your system. I think there's an option in k3b to blank it for you... Oh, just found it, under tools->format/erase rewritable disk. Back in the day we would just do a dd and write zeros over the whole disk, lol. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but is not working, neither KB3 neither the terminal command:  BD/DVD±RW/-RAM format utility by <appro@fy.chalmers.se>, version 7.1.
:-( mounted media doesn't appear to be DVD±RW, DVD-RAM or Blu-ray. ***  In this case the DVD was make "empty" with KB3.  When i redo the same in Windows, it will work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried the old school dd method? `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sr0` And can you please thumb through `udisks --showinfo /dev/sr0` and tell me what it says the dvd-rw is? It should give quite a bit of insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in the mean time i have make all my DVD -RW empty in Windows, and now there is no longer a problem.  I think the problem (as usual) is in Windows, for i can only do this with a old Nero program

Comment: can I use 'cd+rw-format -force=full /dev/sr0' for cd-rw? @darkdragn

Comment: dvd+rw-format -force /dev/sr0 worked, but not "-force=full", which it said was an unimplemented commandline option.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The trick (I found) was to make sure the `/dev` parameter points to the correct device - which in my case made the command:

```
dvd+rw-format -force=full /dev/dvdrw1
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
dvd+rw-format -force=full /dev/dvdrw
```

worked (without the 1 on the end).

It will take about 15 minutes.