# CD/DVD Permissions

Tags: permissions, dvd

Okay, i was burning some videos onto a DVD, and after i finished, took the CD out. Now, trying to use the same CD to burn something of the same series, so i wanted to keep it on one CD, i can't seem to copy and paste, delete, or format the CD, and the permissions have been set so that i can only "Acces Files" or something along those line. So im only allowed to view, or play. This happens with every CD i put in. I can put it in once, and change something, but the next time i try to, the permissions have been set to only allow to to "Access Files" and i can't change it as an admin user, or as "su" through the terminal(though i was trying to use the "gksu nautilus" program)

So, sorry if thats too long, but does anyone know why this keeps happening??? And If so, how to resolve this?

Comment: Please clarify - what medium type and filesystem are you using, and if applicable, which mastering software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add files to a recordable or rewritable disc it must have been written in a **session mode** and **that last session must not be closed** (see this topic: [multisession](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28044/why-is-it-not-possible-to-burn-a-multisession-dvd-using-brasero)). Tracks on a disc that are not in packet mode cannot be modified once written.

Otherwise you need to empty the disc and re-burn all the files as a new session (see: [How do I format a DVD-RW?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47493/how-do-i-format-a-dvd-rw) ) but this only works for rewritables.

This is not something Ubuntu enforces but how (re)writable media work.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Mulitsession can also be used on non-rewritable media.

Comment: so it is best to massacre the 1st part? @soulsource

Comment: Looks good to me now ^^