# How can you delete a folder/file/etc. on a read only DVD+R?

Tags: read-only

I was trying to get my cd mounted (that problem got fixed), but I burned something to my cd as a test and now I can't get it off.

Comment: did you fill the dvd or did you leave space?? you can still use the empty space but the written part is permanently used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a DVD-RW, you need to [format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47493/how-do-i-format-a-dvd-rw) the DVD.

If it's a DVD-+R, usually you can't. However, if your DVD-R writing software used [packet writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_Writing) and a compatible filesytem (e.g. UDF), then it might be possible to make the already written files invisible. Sometimes this is also referred to as writing "sessions". [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28044/why-is-it-not-possible-to-burn-a-multisession-dvd-using-brasero/28058#28058) is how to write such a DVD in Brasero.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an CD-R, you just can't.

If it's an CD-RW you need to delete the disc before adding new content. Delete a folder on CD is nothing I'm aware of it's possible at all. If you need so, you should make a backup of your CD and complete reburn it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said DVD+R.

Comment: Same as for CD-R

Answer (score 1):

You can't, DVD+R is a write-once, read-only disc. you can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BR)